# When I adjust the microphone levels it always goes back to 0. What do I do?

Tags: windows-7, microphone

I´ve got windows 7 and I´ve also got a problem with my external microphone on my desktop. It used to work fine just minutes ago until I restarted my computer. Then the microphone stopped working. The volume bar is at 0 and when I try to change it goes right back down to 0 again. Any suggestions?  PS. I´ve already changed to "Do nothing" on the communication tab.

Comment: Did you verify it is plugged in completely? How about using `System Restore` to go back to a point it worked?

Comment: Do you use Skype or any other VOIP utility that has the option of controlling the microphone? I know Skypes microphone adjustment is somewhat "enthusiastic" at times...

Comment: No I don´t have skype running. but maby System Restore would help. But I´m afraid it will go back when I restart the computer.